# Blender join mesh curve a

Tags: mesh, modifiers, particles, curve-modifier, blender-osm

I have made a fury coat which consists of several objects and some furry sections using particle system modifier. I have to join them to a single object. When I click join, the hair particles are going all over the place. But when I apply the modifiers I am loosing the hair particular..
I am not sure what to do,
I just simply want to combine all the meshes, curves and modifiers as a single mesh.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.
BTW I am using Blend3.0
Zinga

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks - I made a coat using some meshes and curve objects. Currently I have four mesh objects namely buttons, cloths, furs and text. Everything works perfectly, but I want to export this as a single mesh object in an another file. Therefore, I wanted to join them but when I combine them hair particle modifier is getting applied on all the mesh objects. I just want to combine all the mesh objects and end up with a single mesh object. I hope this clarifies things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each object, create a vertex group where the fur is supposed to be, make sure that you give a different name to each vertex group of each object:

[image]

For each object, choose the group in the *Particle System* panel > *Vertex Groups > Density*:

[image]

When you'll join all the objects, it will remove all the particle systems except the one of the last selected object, but you just need to create a new particle system, go into the dropdown menu, select the good particle system, then for each particle system go into *Vertex Groups > Density* select the good vertex group:

[image]

Comment: thanks mate - I will give this a go... much appreciate it

Comment: my apology in advance - I m still fairly new to the blender.
I cant find anything in density vertex group

Comment: I've edited my answer, i hope it helps

Comment: You're a legend... let me try this

Comment: ABSOLUTELY AMAZING!!!!!!!!!!!!! WORKED LIKE A CHARM

Comment: you're welcome  ;)